# Is it possible to use regexp to simulate push stack automata?

Tags: regex

I think it's impossible. In theory Regular expressions are equivalent to finite state automata, not push stack. And I haven't found an appropriate counting method in the JS documentation for Reg Exp.

But when I asked a colleague of mine how would he code a method that test
if a string has a well formed parenthesis sequence, he said "Reg Exp", instead of the well known counter solution.

He did not showed me his reg exp, yet.

Comment: If your friend means true regexes (as opposed to souped-up extensions that most languages/libraries offer), then he is wrong.

Comment: For .NET regex dialect (i.e. not true regex) you might want to take a look at "(?<name1-name2> subexpression)" here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: @Jens, thanks for the link. 
I read half way through and found the example that deal with matching parenthesis.

starts with 
string pattern = "^[^<>]*" +
                       "(" + 
                       "((?'Open'<)[^<>]*)+" +
                       "((?'Close-Open'>)[^<>]*)+" +
                       ")*" +
                       "(?(Open)(?!))$";
      string input = "<abc><mno<xyz>>";

Well, ok. It is possible to use regexp to solve this matching problem, but they are using a loop to do sequential matching tests. Not a true finite state solution, but indeed a valid one.

Comment: You can match balanced structures with regex flavors offering recursion (PCRE, Oniguruma, Boost, PyPi regex Python module) and in .NET using balanced construct. In classical understanding of a regex, this is not possible. In Java, JS, Python re, also ICU regex library, there is no way to match balanced parentheses with regex.